# Fire update event on keyup

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have textbox ("D_find" in its id) on my form witch i use to filter form's data using LIKE query.

I have following code:

```
Private Sub D_find_AfterUpdate()  

    Dim fil  

    fil = Me.D_find  

    If fil = Null Then  
        fil = ""  
    End If  

    Me.Filter = "DeloN Like '" + fil + "*'"  

End Sub
```

It's working correctly if i press tab or focus some other control on form, but i need to apply filter immediatly after keyup event of the textbox, but i cant to it, because if i use this code in D_find_keyup i *always* have D_find is NULL, but in current scenario it's always is not null except if it's empty.

The second trouble present in current scenario: after AfterUpdate fired and filter is applied, text color in D_find textbox is going to be white and it rollbacks to black after i type somethin in this textbox (D_find) or cut some text.

--
I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox still has focus, you can use:

```
NameOfControl.Text
```

This will contain the text just entered. However, why must you apply the filter immediately, it would be safer in Afterupdate, because you would be sure that all data was entered, and you can set focus back to the search control.

EDIT re Comments

Using a textbox, txtSearch, and a listbox, lstCompanies the following code illustrates the above:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
s = "SELECT Key, Company " _
  & "FROM tblCompanies " _
  & "WHERE Company LIKE '*" _
  & Replace(Me.txtSearch.Text, "'", "''") & "*'"

Me.lstCompanies.RowSource = s
End Sub
```

The listbox returns a gradually diminishing list as letters are added to txtSearch.

Comment: It work fine if i use AfterUpdate, but it's "too late". I need "live filter". If i use Change or KeyUp event of NameOfControl i always have Null for NameOfControl.Text or NameOfControl.Value, also if i use NameOfControl.SetFocus before reading value i also recive Null.

Comment: I have added more notes. If it does not work for you, there may be some other underlying problem. It is often worthwhile testing with a new form.